# attach a damaged mdf file in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2012 I am trying to attach a .mdf file to a database. The thing is there were still open transactions when my server was shut down. Then I reinstall the server and I have deleted the .ldf file.

Now when I try to attach the .mdf file in SSMS, an error says without .ldf file a .mdf file cannot be attached because there was open transaction.

Does anyone know a solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: what you are getting error?

Comment: You can only attach SQL Server data file without log file if t was `cleanly` shutdown and no running transaction was their. In your case SQL Server is not sure about status of transaction which was forcefully closed so cannot bring database online

Comment: But why does the title say "damaged mdf file" while what are you talking about is missing ldf file while there were open transactions on shutting down? Is it really damaged, your mdf file?

Answer (score 2):

Ypu can use hack attach method described by Paul Randal here:
[hack-attach a damaged database](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-hack-attach-a-damaged-database/)

> To attach the database you need to fool SQL Server into thinking it’s
>   already attached. The set of steps to go through are as follows:
>
> This only works if the server instance you’re using is the same
>   version as the database you’re trying to attach
>
> - Create a dummy database, with the same name, the same number of data    and log files, with the exact same file names (extremely
>     important!)    and same file IDs (make sure you have instant file
>     initialization    enabled so the file creations don’t take ages – see
>     this blog post).    This can be tricky to do if you had added or
>     removed files to the    database before it was corrupted, but you need
>     to make sure the file    IDs are exactly the same.
> - Set the dummy database offline (ALTER DATABASE RealDatabaseName SET    OFFLINE) or shut the server down
> - Delete all the data and log files from the dummy database
> - Drop in as many of the data and log files from the damaged database    as possible
> - Set the dummy database online (ALTER DATABASE    RealDatabaseName SET    ONLINE) or start the server if you shut it down    for step 2

In your case you should delete both mdf and ldf files of newly created database and copy only your mdf to the file location.

Your database will be attached but cannot run recovery, so it will be marked as `SUSPECT`
Then you can try to put it into `EMERGECY` mode and extract as much data as possible.

Seee here an example: [Using EMERGENCY mode to access a RECOVERY PENDING or SUSPECT database](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-4-using-emergency-mode-to-access-a-recovery-pending-or-suspect-database/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I couldnt figure out the instant file initialization. So I recreated all tables in that database because I have all the data input and SQL script.

Answer (score 1):

**Attach MDF File Without LDF file by using T-SQL script:** You can run a TSQL Script on SQL Query to attach your MDF file and recreate your transaction log file.

**Method 1:**

```
Create Database testdb ON
(FILENAME=N'C:\File location of your mdf file\testdb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
Go
```

For Example Here `testdb.mdf` is your (`.mdf`) file name.

**Note :** These methods will work only if your database is cleanly `shut down` and you have a healthy `MDF` file database. Be sure you have valid mdf file backup.

**Method 2:**

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Testdb] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\File location of your mdf file\Testdb.mdf' )
FOR ATTACH
GO
```

**Trying to Attach the Damaged SQL Server Database**

You can also use stored procedure to attach the (.mdf) file without (.ldf) file.

```
USE master 
GO 

EXEC sys.sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'TestDB', 
    @physname = N'C:\File location of your mdf file\TestDBCopy.mdf' 
GO
```

**Note:**

> This feature (`sp_attach_single_file_db`) will be removed in a future
>   version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. We recommend that you use CREATE DATABASE database_name
>   FOR ATTACH instead. For more information, see CREATE DATABASE (SQL
>   Server Transact-SQL). Do not use this procedure on a replicated
>   database.
>
> We recommend that you do not attach or restore databases from unknown
>   or untrusted sources. Such databases could contain malicious code that
>   might execute unintended Transact-SQL code or cause errors by
>   modifying the schema or the physical database structure. Before you
>   use a database from an unknown or untrusted source, run DBCC CHECKDB
>   on the database on a nonproduction server and also examine the code,
>   such as stored procedures or other user-defined code, in the database.

For your further ref [Here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/07/03/attach-mdf-data-file-without-ldf-log-file-interview-question-week-078/) & [Here](http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/how-to-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file/) and [How to Attach a SQL Server Database without a Transaction Log and with Open Transactions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3579/how-to-attach-a-sql-server-database-without-a-transaction-log-and-with-open-transactions/)